# Sub-menu not showing up after screen resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to build a custom responsive navigation that changes to a 100% width pulldown menu for mobile. I have some javascript that hides any sub menu items that may be open if the window is resized to a new breakpoint (it changes at 768px). However, if I open the sub menu at the mobile size (less than 768px) and then resize the window suddenly the hover effect doesn't work and the sub menu items do not show up on the larger screen size.

Here is a JSFiddle of the stripped down version of my navigation https://jsfiddle.net/5h5bhwu4/2/

The only part that I think might be causing the problem is this javascript:

```
    if (w > 768) {
        $("#nav > li > ul").hide();
    }
```

If click on the first menu item at low screen size, then resize the window it will not show the same sub menu when you hover over the parent item. But if you start at a larger screen size (or if you don't open the sub menu in the low screen size) it will work fine. I think the problem is in the javascript but I can't see anything that would stop this sub menu from showing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the hover effect on JS, not on CSS.

When you see the size of the window:

```
if (w > 768) {
    $("#nav > li > ul").hide();
    // Put hover here
}
```

You need to force the hover, and you can't do it with the CSS

Answer (score 0):

When you say `.hide()`, it adds inline style `display:none` which overwrites the style all the time. Best is to have a class and add that class.

```
  if (w > 768) {
            $("#nav > li > ul").removeAttr('style'); // this is for the style added on slideToggle
            $("#nav > li > ul").addClass('hidden');
        }

CSS

.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5h5bhwu4/4/)